# `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paramMap')`. Karma error message - Angular testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine

I've recently been learning of Angular Testing. So i created a component that is being used by the router based on a number id.

Inside my component's code i get the id value using this:

```
id = 0;
getId : number () {
  this.id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
}
```

My test spec.ts file is as follows:

```
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { of } from 'rxjs';
    import { RoutingByIdComponent } from './routing-by-id.component';
    
    describe('RoutingByIdComponent', () => {
      let component: RoutingByIdComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<RoutingByIdComponent>;
      const activatedRouteMock = {
        paramMap: of({ get: (param: string) => '1' }), 
      };
    
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [RoutingByIdComponent],
          providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock }],
        }).compileComponents();
      });
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RoutingByIdComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

After "ng test" command i get error message on Karma:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'paramMap')`

If i declare id value as `id = 0` without getting it from the **ActivatedRoute** test works just fine!

So the problem occurs by the usage of the `getId()` function and the **ActivatedRoute**.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

you can mock the activatedRoute with jasmine. I set this up in my component

```
private activatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);

ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  this.callMe(id);
}
callMe(id: any) {
  console.log('Called with id: ', id);
}
```

and this is my spec:

```
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
    import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
    import { ActivatedRoute, convertToParamMap } from '@angular/router';

    fdescribe("AppComponent", () => {
        let component: AppComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
        let activatedRoute: jasmine.SpyObj<ActivatedRoute>;
        const snapshot = {
            paramMap: convertToParamMap({ id: 1 })
        };

        beforeEach(async () => {

            await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                providers: [
                    {
                        provide: ActivatedRoute,
                        useValue: activatedRoute
                    }
                ],
                imports: []
            }).compileComponents();
        });

        activatedRoute = jasmine.createSpyObj('ActivatedRoute', [], { snapshot });

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            activatedRoute = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute) as jasmine.SpyObj<ActivatedRoute>;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });

        it('should call callMe with the correct id', () => {
            const id = 1;
            spyOn(component, 'callMe');

            component.ngOnInit();

            expect(component.callMe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(id);
        });
    });
```